# Why is this method returning null even though the underlying controller is mocked using Spocks' Mock()?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, grails-plugin, spock

```
import grails.plugin.spock.*

class EventControllerSpec extends ControllerSpec {

    def "Creating a breadcrumb from an event"() {
        given: "I have a named event"
        def eventController = Mock(EventController)
        def event   = Mock(Event)
        event.title >> 'Space-Journey with Sprock and the Crew'
        event.title == 'Space-Journey with Sprock and the Crew'

        when: "I create a breadcrumb from it"
        def eventCrumb = eventController.createCrumb("Event", "show", "1", event.title)

        /*
        private Map createCrumb (String controllerName, String actionName, String id, String msg) {
        msg = (msg ? msg : "cr.breadcrumb.${controllerName}.${actionName}")
        [ 'controller':controllerName,
        'action':actionName,
        'id':id,
        'message':msg
        ]
         */

        then: "I receive a map where the message-value is the events' title"
        eventCrumb.message == event.title
    }
}
```

note the commented out method which is in the EventController

1. Why does the snippet cause "**Cannot get property 'message' on null object**"?
2. How can I setup the snippet correctly?
3. Generally, will/won't I need any of the *mockTagLib*, *mockController*, *mockLogging* GrailsUnitTestCase functions when using **Spock**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unit testing a controller there is a convention which automatically sets the controller up for you. Just refer to the `controller` in your test as follows;

```
import grails.plugin.spock.*

class EventControllerSpec extends ControllerSpec {

  def "Creating a breadcrumb from an event"() {
    given: "I have a named event"
    def event = Mock(Event)
    event.title >> 'Space-Journey with Sprock and the Crew'

    when: "I create a breadcrumb from it"
    def eventCrumb = controller.createCrumb("Event", "show", "1", event.title)

    /*
    private Map createCrumb (String controllerName, String actionName, String id, String msg) {
    msg = (msg ? msg : "cr.breadcrumb.${controllerName}.${actionName}")
    [ 'controller':controllerName,
    'action':actionName,
    'id':id,
    'message':msg
    ]
     */

    then: "I receive a map where the message-value is the events' title"
    eventCrumb.message == event.title
  }
}
```

You don't need to explicitly mock the controller as `ControllerSpec` does it for you, however, you may need to mock other elements that your controller is using. Sometimes it is sufficient to add these through the controller's metaclass

Comment: Great! Thanks, mfloryan.

Which, in this context (?), it the controllers' metaclass?

Comment: For users of later versions of Grails (2.3.x), this issue appears to have cropped back up, now that Spock is part of Grails tests by default. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11239