# Does the coverage plugin (Cobertura under the hood) report on Spock specifications?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, code-coverage, cobertura, spock

With `grails test-app unit:spock -coverage` I ran the test explained at

"[Why is this method returning null even though the underlying controller is mocked using Spocks' Mock()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671828/why-is-this-method-returning-null-even-though-the-underlying-controller-is-mocked)"

Now the coverage report "thinks" that the method *createCrumb* has not been tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had a typo in my command. As type I wrote *spoc* instead of *spock*, **causing no tests to run** at all.

`grails test-app unit:spoc -coverage`

After changing this to the correct values, the tests were actually run and the coverage report contained them.

So: **YES, the coverage plugin DOES report on Spock specifications**.